# Can I use Spring MVC 3 with GAE, even if it is not mentioned (or actualised) in "Will it play in Java"?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc

My question is in the title.

I am afraid to use Spring MVC 3 (and learn it..) and having bad surprise after.

Do you have any recent feedback or recommendation about using SPRING MVC + GAE ?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Spring MVC 3. Search the web and you'll find numerous tutorials and mini-examples on how to use it on App Engine.

That said, you should prefer a more lightweight solution, because big frameworks can suffer from slow start-up times. There are workarounds specific for Spring MVC, like [this blog post suggests](http://localstreamer.posterous.com/gae-google-app-engine-spring-mvc-how-to-solve).

Comment: You could of course use the [always on](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Always_On) feature to avoid the slow start-up. Or set up a cron job that pings the server often enough. I've been successfully using Spring MVC3 for more than a year with App Engine.